# Passing a variable into a function - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<button id="capIt" class="preview" ng-click="saveCaption('{{ user_id }}')">
  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save It!
</button>
```

Which, when inspected in the DOM, translates to e.g. this:

```
<button id="capIt" class="preview" ng-click="saveCaption('123')">
  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save It!
</button>
```

I have a function inside my controller:
`capApp.controller('mainController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', 
        function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location) {
          $scope.saveCaption = function(user_id) {
            console.log('clicked '+user_id);
            // plus other stuff but that's irrelevant
          }
  }]);`

But when the button is clicked what I see in the console is this:

```
clicked {{ user_id }}
```

Why is the code correct in the DOM but the function is getting `{{ user_id }}` instead of `123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `user_id` instead of `{{user_id}}`

Your variable is in scope, so any value will be picked up directly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to scape user id as you are already in "code".

Try:

```
<button id="capIt" class="preview" ng-click="saveCaption(user_Id)">
   <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save It!
</button>
```